# How do i check if something contains XY, but it can also be XZY?

Tags: c#, user-input

Here is the code

```
    Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
    string greeting = Console.ReadLine();
    if (greeting.ToLower().Contains("hello how are you")) ;
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am good");
    }
```

This code has a problem, if the user says something like `Hello jfjf how fjjffj are you` the program would still reply to him. What i need is `greeting` has to be `Hello`, then X amount of any string (where each string would be split by a space) , `how are you`, so something like `Hello thomas anderson how are you` would work but something like `Hello 8grrgh how jrjr are me you` would not work

Comment: You have to check foreach word that you have into your string if it is contained into your greeting's string

Comment: Have a look at regular expressions (Regex class in .NET).

Comment: @HimBromBeere Point to the right direction, how you can identity: `hello tom how are you` and `hello asdasdasdasdas how are you`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you´ll need a regex for this:

```
var r = new Regex("Hello .* how are you");
if(r.IsMatch(myString)) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("I am good");
}
```

This will match `"Hello thomas anderson how are you"` but not `"Hello jfjf how fjjffj are you"`.

Answer (score 1):

I tested like this on Visual studio and worked fine.

```
            Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
            string greeting = Console.ReadLine();
            if (greeting.ToLower().StartsWith("hello") && greeting.ToLower().EndsWith("how are you")) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I am good");
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below sample code to achieve it

```
private static bool CheckStringExists(string input, string userInput)
        {
            var inputArray = input.ToLower().Split(' ');
            var userInputArray = userInput.ToLower().Split(' ');

            int i = 0, j = 0;
            while (i < inputArray.Length && j < userInputArray.Length)
            {
                if (inputArray[i] == userInputArray[j])
                {
                    i++;
                }
                j++;
            }

            return i == inputArray.Length;
        }
```

You can call the above method as

```
if (CheckStringExists("hello how are you", greeting)) ;
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am good");
    }
```

Here is the working code [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/t2sovX)